# Want to call rel attribute with out click using Jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-plugins

This is a button code
 < input id="error_" type="button" class="tabButton" value="test" rel="#ErrorMessage" />

and this is a div tag code

```
<div id="ErrorMessage" style="border:thin solid black;" class="apple_overlayErrorMessage">
      <div class="contentWrap"></div>
  </div>
```

and this is a css code for overlay

.apple_overlayErrorMessage {

```
/* initially overlay is hidden */
display:none;
/*background-color:transparent;
/* growing background image */
background-image:url(images/ErrorBackground.png);

/* 
    width after the growing animation finishes
    height is automatically calculated
*/
width:100px;    


/* some padding to layout nested elements nicely  */
/*padding: 0px 600px -600px;

/* a little styling */  
font-size:12px;
```

}

When click on the button div tag is call and overlay appears and it works fine but according to my new requirement need to call with out any button click using jquery or javaScript.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
         //Your code for overlay
    })
```

Comment: You can add function for your overlay and call this function while onload.

Comment: The problem is this. how to perform button click functionality with out button click

Comment: You can try this one: take an example:-
    $(document).ready(function() {
example(); 
function example(){ 
// your button click code here... 
}
    })

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do that using jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ErrorMessage").show();
    });
```